# textX: How to generate object names with ObjectProcessors?

Tags: textx

I have a simple example model where I would like to generate names for the objects of the `Position` rule that were not given a name with `as <NAME>`. This is needed so that I can find them later with the built-in FQN scope provider.

My idea would be to do this in the `position_name_generator` object processor but that will be only be called after the whole model is parsed. I don´t really understand the reason for that, since by the time I would need a `Position` object in the `Project`, the objects are already created, still the object processor will not be called.

Another idea would be to do this in a custom scope provider for `Position.location` which would then first do the name generation and then use the built-in FQN to find the `Location` object. Although this would work, I consider this hacky and I would prefer to avoid it.

What would be the textX way of solving this issue?

(Please take into account that this is only a small example. In reality a similar functionality is required for a rather big and complex model. To change this behaviour with the generated names is not possible since it is a requirement.)

```py
import textx


MyLanguage = """
    Model
        :   (locations+=Location)*
            (employees+=Employee)*
            (positions+=Position)*
            (projects+=Project)*
        ;

    Project
        :   'project' name=ID
            ('{'
                ('use' use=[Position])*
            '}')?
        ;

    Position
        :   'define' 'position' employee=[Employee|FQN] '->' location=[Location|FQN] ('as' name=ID)?
        ;

    Employee
        :   'employee' name=ID   
        ;

    Location
        :   'location' name=ID
            ( '{'
                (sub_location+=Location)+
            '}')?
        ;

    FQN
        :   ID('.' ID)*
        ;

    Comment:
      /\/\/.*$/
    ;                
"""

MyCode = """
    location Building
    {
        location Entrance
        location Exit
    }

    employee Hans
    employee Juergen

    // Shall be referred to with the given name: "EntranceGuy"
    define position Hans->Building.Entrance as EntranceGuy 
    // Shall be referred to with the autogenerated name: <Employee>"At"<LastLocation>
    define position Juergen->Building.Exit                  

    project SecurityProject
    {
        use EntranceGuy
        use JuergenAtExit
    }
"""


def position_name_generator(obj):
    if "" == obj.name:
        obj.name = obj.employee.name + "At" + obj.location.name


def main():
    meta_model = textx.metamodel_from_str(MyLanguage)
    meta_model.register_scope_providers({
        "Position.location": textx.scoping.providers.FQN(),
    })

    meta_model.register_obj_processors({
        "Position": position_name_generator,
    })

    model = meta_model.model_from_str(MyCode)
    assert model, "Could not create model..."


if "__main__" == __name__:
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## What is the textx way to solve this...

The use case you describe is to **define the name of an object based on other model elements**, including a reference to other model elements. This is currently not part of any test and use cases included in our test suite and the textx docu.

Object processors are executed at defined stages during model construction (see http://textx.github.io/textX/stable/scoping/#using-the-scope-provider-to-modify-a-model). In the described setup they are executed after reference resolution. Since the name to be defined/deduced itself is required for reference resolution, **object processors cannot be used here** (even if we allow to control when object processors are executed, before or after scope resolution, the described setup still will not work).

Given the dynamics of model loading (see http://textx.github.io/textX/stable/scoping/#using-the-scope-provider-to-modify-a-model), **the solution is located within a scope provider** (as you suggested). Here, we allow to control the order of reference resolution, such that references to the object being named by a custom procedure are postponed, until references required to deduce/define the name resolved.

## Possible workaround

A preliminary sketch of how your use case can be solved is discussed in a https://github.com/textX/textX/pull/194 (with an attached issue https://github.com/textX/textX/issues/193). This textx PR contains a version of scoping.py you could probably use for your project (just copy and rename the module). A full-fledged solution could be part of the textx TEP-001, where we plan to make scoping more controllable to the end-user.

Playing around with this absolutely interesting issue revealed new aspects to me for the textx framework.

- **names dependent on model contents** (involving unresolved references). This name resolution, which can be Postponed (in the referenced PR, see below), in terms of our reference resolution logic.
- Even more interesting are the consequences of that: **What happens to references pointing to locations, where unresolved names are found?** Here, we must postpone the reference resolution process, because we cannot know if the name might match when resolved...

Your example is included: https://github.com/textX/textX/blob/analysis/issue193/tests/functional/test_scoping/test_name_resolver/test_issue193_auto_name.py

Comment: I don´t understand the following part of your answer:

`(even if we allow to control when object processors are executed, before or after scope resolution, the described setup still will not work).`

I think in my use-case it would be more than enough if the object processor for "Position" would be called after the reference resolution is finished for the object.

Comment: References are not processed (resolved) in a top-to-bottom order. Reference resolution can be postponed, thus it is not possible to define that an object processor is called after reference resolution of a single element (in a simple manner). At the moment your object processor is called after all references are resolved. We were discussing to execute certain object processors before reference resolution, but we did not find good use cases for it (and it does not solve your problem).